# Can I hook a method to my php file, that if any page crashes should email me the page and error?

Tags: php, error-handling

I am wondering if I can hook a method in a include, that will email me the debug logs if any of my pages (that uses that include) crashed.

Is there a method that is executed after a fatal error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `register_shutdown_function()` for this. You pass a function name as a parameter to this function, and that function is called when the application exits, for whatever reason.

You can use this time to catch and log any fatal errors, but you can't *recover* from them (they are fatal, after all). I think encounter a fatal error within this function, it's game over. There's no logging that.

In your shutdown function, you'll want to check if the shutdown was due to a fatal error and run logging code if it was:

```
function shutdown() {
  $lastError = error_get_last(); // returns an array with error information:
    switch($lastError['type']){
      case E_ERROR:
      case E_PARSE:
      case E_CORE_ERROR:
      case E_CORE_WARNING:
      case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
      case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
          // log the fatal error
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also similar and other examples listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error

Answer (score 1):

You can catch all errors but fatal errors using [`set_error_handler()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). Unfortunately even "harmless" things like calling undefined functions are fatal and cannot be handled.

However, you can enable `error_log` in php.ini and set it to log errors to syslog. You'll also get fatal errors in this log.

Comment: You can catch fatal errors using `register_shutdown_function()` as well. Also, you should know that there is also a `set_exception_handler()` which acts like `set_error_handler()` but for uncaught exceptions.

Comment: @Agent: How to determine why the script shut down? If you know that, please answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410632/handle-fatal-errors-in-php-using-register-shutdown-function).

Comment: @TheifMaster: I left an answer on *this* question, since I didn't see your comment until your question had already been answered. It's relevant here as well, after all.