# How to iterate over php error and continue while loop?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am using the following code to parse definitions from a remote website , according to the usernames in my database. I am using simple html dom parser.

```
//database connection
include 'db.php';
//display errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

//select usernames order alphabetically
$row = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_name FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM store 
  ORDER BY user_id DESC) 
  AS store ORDER BY user_id ASC");

//echo out definitions of usernames
while($lastusers = mysqli_fetch_array($row)) {
    echo '<br>' . $lastusers["user_name"];
    echo '<br>Definition:<br>';
    $html = file_get_html("https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/" . $lastusers["user_name"]);
    $title = $html->find("div.card-primary-content", 0)->innertext;
    echo $title;

    //save definitions to corresponding username 
    $save = mysqli_query($conn, 'UPDATE  store
    SET     def = $title,
    WHERE   user_name = $lastusers["user_name"]'
    )
}
```

My while loop will begin to generate the definitions per username , until certain pages are not found resulting in an error that stops the loop.

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colourings):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in
>   /app/simple_html_dom.php on line 75 Fatal error: Call to a member
>   function find() on boolean in /app/test.php on line 18

My question is how to skip over the username that throws the error and continue the loop? Also because their are over 500 usernames , this operation is very intensive , so i'm saving the definitions , and would like to avoid the errors being saved to the database.

Comment: Use a try/catch block inside of your loop.

Comment: @aynber can't catch what throws no exception in the first place ... this is a simple warning message.

Comment: Fatal errors in PHP are not Exceptions

Comment: @CBroe Oh, right, good point.

Comment: You can also suppress errors in PHP (although I wouldn't suggest it) using `@` - see this question for more information about error suppression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php

Comment: Your code marked `save definitions to corresponding username` has several pretty big issues, the query itself isn't surrounded by quotes, you are using string concatenation (should use [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)) AND you are missing the ending parenthesis of `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Another way would be to replace `file_get_html` with `file_get_contents`, and passing in an HTTP stream context that has `ignore_errors` set to true (that would avoid the warning AFAIK). Then, check the status code, and if that does not indicate an error, you can feed the HTML code to `str_get_html` to create the parser object and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the warning like shown in the following link

[How can I handle the warning of file_get_contents() function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php)

Or an other alternative is to write a custom error handler. See this link

[PHP: How to use set_error_handler() to properly deal with all errors except notices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217994/php-how-to-use-set-error-handler-to-properly-deal-with-all-errors-except-noti)