# Codeigniter - Send email with exception details

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, exception

I'm googling this topic but I didn't find it.

I would like to receive an email with the exception details ocurred in a codeigniter project.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I don't have because I don't know where to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement PHP's set error handler and set exception handler

1. [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)
2. [set_exception_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Also, check out : [PHP: How to use set_error_handler() to properly deal with all errors except notices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217994/php-how-to-use-set-error-handler-to-properly-deal-with-all-errors-except-noti)