# How do I handle parse and fatal errors?

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error, parse-error

I wrote a custom error handler for my site and I'm aware that PHP doesn't allow handling of parse and fatal errors. Is there something I can do to make it handle these errors? I don't want them being outputted to the user (but I want to use my error handler for them).

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle fatal errors in PHP using register_shutdown_function()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410632/handle-fatal-errors-in-php-using-register-shutdown-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can't parse your script, it won't be able to parse your custom error handler.

You should have `display_errors` off in your `php.ini` and also set `error_reporting` to none when your site is in production.

Also, I believe `set_error_handler()` *can* handle fatal errors.

Comment: ^ What he said, there are good reasons that your script fails on parse errors, it simply does not know what to do

Comment: Was afraid of that. Oh well. And no, I already had set_error_handler() on it and it didn't work.

Comment: As at PHP 7.4.10, `set_error_handler()` does not still handle fatal errors; just set `display_error` to off, this works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php). If there is an error (even parse one) in one of files you have included/required this function will still be called.

Though you won't be able to use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) because shutdown function will be called outside of your error, you could try to use [`error_get_last`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) to get some information about the error.