# Is it possible to catch all PHP errors occured in a file

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to catch all PHP errors (E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_NOTICE,..) in a page and log it to MongoDB in order to read and comment better on it.

I found a way to catch last occured error with 'error_get_last' and send it to anywhere i want with 'register_shutdown_function' [Handle fatal errors in PHP using register_shutdown_function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410632/handle-fatal-errors-in-php-using-register-shutdown-function)

But what if my file have more than one errors, like warnings and notices, how can i get all errors in a file? Is this possible? What i need is something like 'error_get_all'.

Here you can find my code, this code has one fatal error, two warning and one notice:

```
function shutdown() {
  $error = error_get_last();
  if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR || $error['type'] === E_WARNING || $error['type'] === E_NOTICE) {
    var_dump($error);
  }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

spl_autoload_register('foo');

$x = 5;
$y = 0;

echo 'x/y: ' . $x / $y . '<br/>';

foreach ($noarray as $noelement) {
  echo 'no element: ' . $noelement . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to combine solutions:

Use 'set_error_handler' to catch all possible errors it can (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), as well as using the described register_shutdown_function to log the errors which are missed by this.

By doing this, non-fatal errors during runtime will be caught by the custom handler, continuing on until end of script or a fatal error occurs which would be caught by either the custom or the shutdown function depending on type.

Comment: Thanks @lng, combining register_shutdown_function and set_error_handler resolved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined
>   function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING,
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the
>   file where set_error_handler() is called.

Comment: set_error_handler is not solving for my problem, what i need to do is handling error types defined by PHP. shutdown_register_function with error_get_last can handle last error, but not all of them in a file.

Comment: what do you mean all? PHP will *stop* on the first ERROR.

Answer (score 3):

For catching fatal errors and parsing errors you're using right funciton

```
register_shutdown_function
```

But when application reach fatal error, or parsing or any error E_ERROR the process of execution ending at that point of the script, so in this case you can catch only one such a error in script.

I will suggest you to use `register_shutdown_function` just in case to catch fatal errors, and other errors catch with function `set_error_handler` to catch other errors as warning etc, for exceptions `set_exception_handler` by that you can easy track all errors in system and validate them also.

If you will write object for error handling then the logic for you can be:

```
$handler = new Handler();
$handler->handleExceptions(); //using set_exception_handler exceptions
$handler->handleError(E_ALL); //using set_error_handler all other errors
$handler->handleShutdown(); //using register_shutdown_function fatals, parsing
```

By that you will have options to turn off/on errors and store errors where you need them or send by email from one place, also simple way to get full error for debuging.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to use a framework like this:
http://code.google.com/p/lagger/

Answer (score -1):

Fatal errors past the first one encountered are impossible to catch, as the PHP interpreter never reaches them (the script terminates after it executes your shutdown handler). Non-fatal errors can be caught (you will need a separate `error_handler` installed for them in addition to your shutdown handler), PHP won't terminate the script so if you don't terminate it in your error handler either, execution will continue after each non-fatal error and you will catch them all. If you want to still terminate *after* the entire file has been executed, you might want to keep a flag somewhere, clear it before you include the file and raise it in case of error; after the file has been included, you can test this flag and see if any error has been caught. Keep in mind that the included file will have fully executed at that point (if it did not have any fatal errors) or you might never reach that point (if it has fatal errors).

If you're running untrusted user code, you might be interested in [Runkit Sandboxes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php). You can also take a look at [runkit_lint_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-lint-file.php) for some pre-include validation.