# how do i run function if fatal error is occurred using php?

Tags: php

I am new with php.

I am trying to run function if fatal error is occurred while trying to run another function like that

```
try
{
   something
}  
catch()
{
   if error try another thing
}
```

I searched about this problem and i found these threads

[Handle fatal errors in PHP using register_shutdown_function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410632/handle-fatal-errors-in-php-using-register-shutdown-function)

[How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

But i didn't get how to run another function if error occurred

Hope i explained my problem well enough

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first thread you linked is the one you want.

Comment: What part of [**the answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410769/2341603) you yourself linked to didn't you understand? Just put the reference to your function where that answer states that a fatal error has occurred.

Comment: If you're having trouble getting it to work, post what you tried and we'll help you. But we can't explain the general process any better than those questions.

Comment: You must post more code if you want to receive a viable solution. And are you sure you want to catch a "fatal error"? I have the impression, that you actually want to catch an exception, but your code doesn't work yet.